# Consolidate data from multiple sheets

Tags: excel, vba, loops, autofilter

I was hoping to get some help to develop a VBA code to do the following activity. I have a data table which has various activities based on dates. I want to create a summary table based on date criteria. For example if my input is between June 2021 - August 2021, I would like a summary table which shows date, the activity and concatenate (Type + Sub type + Change type)

Any help is deeply appreciated!

[image: Data Table]

[image: Summary Table]

Comment: Could you please describe in more detail what exactly *... my input...* means?

Comment: I mean to say Date range. If I input Today() + 120 days, the summary should show June activities and July activities. If its Today() + 270 days days then June- October and December. Since the data set does not November dates, it will not show.

Answer (score 0):

Try making a *Pivot Table*. Then make a *Calculated Field* to create the concatenation (more detail here: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/calculate-values-in-a-pivottable-11f41417-da80-435c-a5c6-b0185e59da77)

Kind Regards

MTwem

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! Much appreciated. Since the dates are bucketed into multiple columns, I do not know if I can filter a date range to generate a similar summary. I will work towards figuring it out.

Comment: @user7793542 You'll need to unpivot the date columns.  And merged cells are always a PITA.